# check input type file with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can I check inut field's of the type file (size, ending(jpg, png, ...))?
On [my page](http://skeptar.bplaced.net/Design_3.0/index.php?content=create_tutorial) you can add more input field's of the type file if you press on the button "Schritt hizufügen". Here is jquery code for this:

```js
    var max_fields      = 11; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".all_steps"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $("#add_step"); //Add button ID
    var remove_step     = $("#remove_step");
    
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    add_button.click(function(){ //on add input button click
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            wrapper.append('<div class="step"><div class="header_step">Schritt '+ x +' des Tutorial\'s</div><div class="body_step"><a class="create_tutorial_a">Titel des Schrittes</a><input name="input_title_name'+x+'" class="create_tutorial_input" type="text" /><br><a class="create_tutorial_a">Bild</a><input type="file" id="input_image_name'+x+'" name="input_image_name'+x+'"/><br><br><a class="create_tutorial_a_full_width">Beschreibung des Schrittes</a><br><textarea class="create_tutorial_textarea" name="input_description_name'+x+'"></textarea></div>');
            x++;
        }
    });
```

And if you press on the button "Erstellen" it check if every input field is filled. I want a extension, that it will check the input field's of type file (ending, size, ...). My submit function:

```js
 $('form.send').on('submit', function(){

        var empty = false;
        
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
            if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                $(this).addClass("empty_field");
                empty = true;
            }
            else{
                $(this).removeClass("empty_field");
            }
        });

        $('textarea').each(function(){
            if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                $(this).addClass("empty_field");
                empty = true;
            }
            else{
                $(this).removeClass("empty_field");
            }
        });
   )};
```

And here is the form:

```html
        <form method="post" action="index.php?content=write_tutorial" class="send" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="step">
                <div class="header_step">Allgemeines zum Tutorial</div>
                <div class="body_step">
                    <a class="create_tutorial_a">Titel des Tutorial's</a><input class="create_tutorial_input" type="text" name="input_tutorialtitle_name"/>
                    <br>
                    <a class="create_tutorial_a">Autor des Tutorial's</a><input class="create_tutorial_input" type="text" name="input_tutorialauthor_name"/>
                    <br><br>
                    <a class="create_tutorial_a_full_width">Beschreibung des Tutorial's</a>
                    <br>
                    <textarea class="create_tutorial_textarea" name="input_tutorialdescription_name"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="all_steps">
            
            </div>
        
            <div class="step">
                <div class="body_step">
                    <input class="create_button" type="submit" value="Erstellen"/>
                    <input type="button" class="create_button" id="add_step" value="Schritt hinzufügen"/>
                    <input type="button" class="create_button" id="remove_step" value="Schritt entfernen"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I have really no idea. I searched alot now, but I didnt found a good link, which explain it good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the accepts attribute. Change this section of your JS:

```
<input type="file" id="input_image_name'+x+'" name="input_image_name'+x+'"  accept="image/png, image/jpeg" />
```

For file size you can use Javascript:

```
var size = document.getElementById("input_image_name1").files[0].size;
```

But be sure to do these checks server-side too, doing it client-side should just be seen as a usability feature, especially if the site is being exposed to the unwashed public.